# matplotlib scatter color from pandas data frame

Tags: python, matplotlib

What I'd like to do is create a matlab scatter plot as below, but color the dots according to the the string in column C, for example, yes = blue and no = red.

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
 A = pd.DataFrame.from_items([('A', [1, 2, 3]), ('B', [4, 5, 6]), ('C', ['yes', 'yes', 'no'])])


plt.scatter(A['A'], A['B'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary of (value: color) pairs and use those values as `color` argument on `plt.scatter` using a list comprehension.

```
colors = {'yes': 'b', 'no': 'r'}

plt.scatter(A['A'], A['B'], color=[colors[r] for r in A['C']])
```

---

**EDIT:** Preferred way to add legend is to iterate over unique classes in your dataset and use `legend` argument. So we can iterate over the dataframe grouped by `C` and plot them individually with label arguments. And finally call `plt.legend()` to show it.

```
colors = {'yes': 'b', 'no': 'r'}

for idx, row in A.groupby('C'):
    plt.scatter(row['A'], row['B'], 
                color=[colors[r] for r in row['C']], 
                label=idx)

plt.legend()
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to create a legend with this info as well?

Comment: @Sparky_47 I'm sure there are other ways but preferred method from `matplotlib` is to iterate over unique classes and use `label` argument. I'll edit the answer with legend for each unique class.

Answer (score 1):

Funny one-liner:

```
plt.scatter(x="A",y="B",c="C",
            data=df.apply(lambda x: [x.A,x.B,chr(int(1.6*ord(x.C[1])-63.6))], axis=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Heh, +1 on the creativity. I would still prefer `plt.scatter(A['A'], A['B'], color=['b' if r=='yes' else 'r' for r in A['C']])` for a one liner (and be boring) but that is pretty cool.